# Usar o campo resposta para fazer um comentário, porque o campo adequado não permite formatação

Tags: debate

Observando a [resposta disponível neste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/59169/8039) optei em votar negativo, justifiquei no comentário por ser a postagem mais uma correção do que uma resposta ao que foi perguntado.

Porém de forma justa, a pessoal que respondeu alegou que o campo de comentário não permite formatação, e que não ficaria adequado postar lá.

Porém percebo que a resposta em questão é uma correção no código que está errado, o que deve ser feito neste caso?

- Corrigir o código?
- Comentar alertando do erro?
- Gerar uma resposta propondo a correção? (como foi feito?)

Answer (score 8):

Eu acho que o caminho é comentar alertando do erro, ou postar uma resposta que explique o erro, mas não deixe de responder o que foi perguntado. Na verdade, a resposta que você indicou não está muito longe disso, o autor poderia facilmente editá-la para explicar como usar uma variável separada e obter a parte fracionária usando a lógica do código atual (apesar de eu preferir a sugestão do Luiz Vieira):

```
float f = A - floor(A);
```

Eu pediria ao autor da resposta que fizesse isso. Se ele não der retorno, complementaria a resposta eu mesmo, correndo o risco de o autor rejeitar/reverter minha edição. Se isso acontecer, seria preciso sinalizar para um moderador converter em comentário.

Tem casos em que a conversão para comentário prejudica a compreensão pela falta da formatação adequada, mas não é bem o caso dessa resposta. Não é difícil explicar que ele está sobrescrevendo a variável, mesmo sem usar nenhum código.

Por fim: nunca corrija código errado nas perguntas, pois o erro geralmente faz parte do problema/dúvida da pessoa. Corrigir código alheio em respostas é permitido, principalmente no caso pequenos erros óbvios (como erros de digitação); alterações mais complexas numa resposta devem ser solicitadas ao autor, e somente serem feitas se ele não se manifestar dentro de um prazo razoável.

Comment: Gostei principalmente desta parte: "**nunca corrija código errado nas perguntas, pois o erro geralmente faz parte do problema/dúvida da pessoa**" - Já vi muitos casos aonde pequenas correções nas perguntas acabam por mudar completamente o sentido do que está sendo perguntado e invalidam respostas que estavam perfeitamente corretas.